# Can I access an APFS drive plugged into a Pi over a network?

Tags: networking, mac-osx, raspbian

I have a SSD that's formatted for APFS Encrypted. I want to plug it into a Raspberry Pi and access it over a LAN from a Mac. However, as far as I know, there isn't a read / write driver for the Pi for APFS.

So, more generally, I was wondering if it's possible for the Pi to give file-system agnostic, low-level access to the SSD over the network, such that only the Mac is dealing with the file system?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if the Pi is configured as a iSCSI target.

This article explains how to do that...

https://www.stephenwagner.com/2020/03/18/how-to-raspberry-pi-4-as-an-iscsi-san-iscsi-target/amp/